# How to create a canvas in HTML5 that looks like a window

Tags: html, canvas

I want to create a HTML page, in which a button click will open a window dialog (a canvas that looks like a window with close and resize options). How do I go ahead creating this design. Any idea?

Comment: open a popup having canvas in it. just a suggetion

Comment: Ah, you mean like those ones that pretend to be a MS window that when you click installs malware? :P

Comment: @Jarrod : yes something like that but it wont install malware :) ..Here the window(or in better words canvas), the user should be able to move around the browser area + resize + have a close button----like a regular window

Comment: Like wisdom suggested, you're really just after a popup with a canvas in it. Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but maybe canvas is not the best solution? Would plain html/JS go the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my requirements, i found solution with [JQueryUI modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) that has re size and dragging.

Special thanks to @wisdom and @Jarrod for their help in finding me a solution.